# Google script to delete rows

Tags: google-apps-script, delete-row

when I use the deleteRows function I get the error :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'deleteRows' of null
    at clearRange(Code:4:4)

here is my code:

```
function clearRange() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
// Rows start at "2" -  delete of N rows (400)
ss.deleteRow(2, 400);
}
```

Can you please help me to solve this issue?

Thanks and regards
Thierry

Comment: Open the required sheet and it should be deleteRows   not deleteRow

Answer (score 2):

As Andres has said, your script may not be attached to your sheet, and you will have to go to the sheet in question and click `Tools > Script Editor`.

However, there are two other possible issues -

- The function is named `deleteRows` and not `deleteRow`
- You're calling `deleteRows()` on a `Spreadsheet` object. It is a `Sheet` function.

If these were the issues, this code should fix it.

```
function clearRange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  // Rows start at "2" -  delete of N rows (400)
  sheet.deleteRows(2, 400);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ss` spreadsheet variable is `null` which means your script is not bound to any spreadsheet as it should be to use the [getActive](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactive) method. You can create a container bound script following the steps explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script):

> To create a bound script, open a Google Sheets, Docs, Slides, or Forms
>   file, then select Tools > Script editor.